# binding the WPF data grid from SqlDataReader object

Tags: c#, .net

How to bind the data in SqlDataReader object into WPF data grid control. I will not know the exact number of columns that will be fetched at run time. So it should dynamically detect the number of columns and attached the data to the grid. 
Thank you for your help.
Smith

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to bind a data reader you can add this code to a static class

```
    public static IEnumerable<System.Data.IDataRecord> AsEnumerable(this System.Data.IDataReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return reader;
        }
    }
```

And then just do

```
myGrid.ItemsSource = myReader.AsEnumerable();
```

I haven't tried that but it *might* work. It also might not work for a number of reasons.

However I think you would be better off binding to a DataTable. It's the same 'era' as a DataReader